# How to route all traffic through Tor and VPN?

Tags: vpn, tor

So I am having some problems routing traffic through TOR & VPN.

My first issue:After installing anonsurf and routing all traffic through Tor in Kali everything works fine.  However when I have my firewall enabled (gufw) anonsurf will not work when I try to surf the web.  It cuts all traffic off to the internet. Does anyone know what the issue is here and why I can't have anonsurf running as well as my firewall at the sametime?

My second issue is if I start anonsurf routing all traffic through tor after boot and then try to log in to my VPN (nord) I cannot connect to my VPN.  The VPN only works if I do not have anonsurf enabled.  If I start the VPN first and try to start anonsurf afterwards I get an error on anonsurf saying couldn't modify resolv.conf operation not permitted.  Is it possible to run anonsurf and a VPN at the same time and if so how would I properly do that?

Answer (score 0):

Anonsurf uses Tor iptables to anonymize the whole system. Running another firewall like gufw results in contradictions.

Running a VPN over Tor is almost always a bad thing to do. The VPN would punch a tunnel through Tor effectively negating Tor Anonymity.

Running Tor over a VPN is acceptable, but the way you're trying to do it is to have anonsurf overide your VPN.

The easiest way to perform anonymous surfing is to use TBB. The **T**or **B**rowser **B**undle is already configured to provide strong anonymity and will work well directly or through a VPN.

Comment: So does TBB route all internet traffic through the Tor system?

Comment: @Rideboards - No, TBB routes all Tor Browser traffic, including DNS, through Tor.

Comment: So what exactly is TBB?  Is TBB just the tor-browser?  I did a search to download TBB and it just seems to be the torbrowser.  Can you explain the differences, if there are any & provide a link to if possible.  As far as a VPN with tor.  The correct route would be to start VPN first then open tor browser?

Comment: @Rideboards - TBB is a Browser configured not to leak information and supports various security/privacy levels, coupled with the Tor agent to provide Tor connections for all Tor Browser activity. https://tb-manual.torproject.org/about/ . Yes VPN first then TBB, but generally you don't need the VPN.